# Custom route for wild card

Tags: wildcards, custom-route

I'm trying to develop a custom route for this use case.
The following URL patterns:

https://example.com/new/Brand-1/product-1.htm

https://example.com/used/Brand-2/product-2.htm

should be redirected to https://example.com/products

The `Brand` & `Product` names in the URL may change, but the relative root will always be either `/new` or `/used`.

When I browse this URL - https://example.com/used/mybrand/myproduct.htm, it throws the error:
[image]

Here is the code:

**RouteConfig.cs:**

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");            

            routes.MapRoute("OldUsed", "used/{make}/{name}", new
            {
                controller = "RedirectToListing",
                action = "RedirectOldVdpToVlp",
                make = "",
                name=""
            });

        }
    }
```

**InitializeRoutes.cs:**

```
public class InitializeRoutes : Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes
    {
        public override void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }        
    }
```

**z_Feature.Base.Pipelines.config:**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="Feature.Base.Pipelines.InitializeRoutes, Feature.Base" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Is this the right way.

Comment: If it helps you could try implementing rewrite/redirect rules in IIS instead of having custom routes defined

Comment: @CristiVulturar I also need to handle some business logic, like getting the brand name from the old url and then redirect to the listing page with that as a query string param. Would that be possible. If yes, could you please share any references.

Comment: You can use redirect rules with regular expressions and backreferences. That is possible. This is just one blog about it: https://isitoktocode.com/post/introduction-to-url-rewriting-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-and-regular-expressions

Comment: Did you add htm extension to `Allowed extensions` in `<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.FilterUrlExtensions, Sitecore.Kernel">`? If this is not done Sitecore will not run `httpRequestBegin` pipeline

Comment: @Jeroen yes i did

Answer (score 1):

You can use IIS Rewrite inbound rules to accomplish this, for example:

```
<rule name="Property URL Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^new/Brand-([0-9]+)/Product-([0-9]+)$" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="/products?brand={R:1}&amp;product={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
</rule>
                    
<rule name="Property URL Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^used/Brand-([0-9]+)/Product-([0-9]+)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/products?brand={R:1}&amp;product={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
</rule>
```

If you have links on the pages aswell you might need to create an outbound rule aswell to handle them, for example https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Thank you. But can this not be done from code. As there could be some complex logic to be handled and also Brand & product were just examples. The names could be any alphanumeric strings.

Comment: For alphanumeric strings you can just change [0-9] to [0-9a-z]. From code you could also look into how the sitecore 301 redirect module is implemented, although that is doing redirect and not rewrite. We have relied on rewrite rules as it is easier to setup the parameters instead of custom routes.